# php change autoincrement id to a new id like youtube

Tags: php

i found this code on a website
328743826 is auto increment id from my database

```
<?php
echo base_convert(328743826, 10, 32);
?>
```

I want to use this code. Now what should do if this code generate a duplicate id that is already in my database

Comment: Choose a value (for '328743826') such that there is no duplicate; and reject the duplication. Also consider using a surrogate or 'external' ID not tied with an auto-increment PK (if such is chosen).

Comment: Coverting base for a number does not introduce collisions, so that's not a problem.

Comment: its mean my base should be same in all links